# How to correctly export NLCD image in Google Earth Engine at native projection and scale?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine

How can I correctly export an NLCD image in Google Earth Engine at its native projection and scale? If I run the following code and open the output in ArcGIS it has the correct projection and scale but it is not in the right location -- the output is in Algeria instead of North Dakota.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/608248a44b9442091e289f5ceb8149d4

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("USGS/NLCD_RELEASES/2016_REL"),
    geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-101.66391157593377, 48.515896785637125],
          [-101.66391157593377, 48.21664117625055],
          [-100.88388227905877, 48.21664117625055],
          [-100.88388227905877, 48.515896785637125]]], null, false);

//get 2001 landcover data for lower 48
var nlcd = imageCollection
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate('2001-01-01', '2001-12-31')
.select('landcover');

//get nlcd native projection and scale
var prj = nlcd.first().projection();
var scl = prj.nominalScale();
print(prj, "Scale:",scl)

//convert to image
var nlcd2001 = nlcd.max();//not albers anymore and scale dependent on zoom

//get focal mode of crop
var crop = nlcd2001.eq(82).focalMode(3);//the final pull (export) should make this happen at native resolution and scale if I understand correctly
print(crop.projection(), "Scale:", crop.projection().nominalScale());
Map.addLayer(crop, {min:0, max:1, palette:['green', 'yellow']}, 'crop fm')

//export image in native scale projection
//takes 1 minute
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: crop,//setting image as nlcd2001 also ends up in Algeria
  scale: 30,
  crs: prj,
  description: 'crop_fm3',
  maxPixels: 70000000000,
  region: geometry//I tried transform on this too
});
```

Comment: You could use the Albers Conical directly (EPSG:5070) during export this should give you the right result. Why your approach doesn't work I have no Idea, I think it definitely should work

Comment: Thanks! I agree -- it should work. I think something must be wrong with the defined projection in GEE. Exporting with epsg:5070 works but pixels are shifted slightly from the original NLCD image -- maybe due to the defined extent...

Comment: I submitted this as a bug to GEE folks, and they promptly and kindly worked through the issue with me. I was told it is an export problem and gdal has trouble with some part of the NLCD projection. I always thought NLCD projection was epsg: 5070, but it's apparently a custom non-epsg projection that is slightly different in some way. So the short answer is @JonasV is right, the best solution is to export NLCD using the 5070 epsg if looking for something close enough. They said they'll add details about this problem in the FAQ.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but I think you should define the WGS84 projection for exporting and opening in Arcgis/QGIS.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: crop,//setting image as nlcd2001 also ends up in Algeria
  scale: 30,
  crs: ee.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
  description: 'crop_fm3',
  maxPixels: 70000000000,
  region: geometry//I tried transform on this too
});
```